# If we're given characteristic and minimal polynomial of a linear transformation, how can we find all its possible Jordan forms?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Determine all possible Jordan forms of a linear transformation with characteristic polynomial $(x−2)^4(x−3)^3$ and minimal polynomial $(x−2)^2(x−3)^2$.

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could edit your post to address any of the following questions. Where did you encounter this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Note also that askers are expected to format any mathematical expressions using Mathjax, for which instructions are [given here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I have changed your question in order to do this, but in the future please do this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The exponent of $(x - \lambda)$ in the characteristic polynomial is the **sum** of the sizes of the Jordan blocks associated with $\lambda$. The exponent of $(x - \lambda)$ in the minimal polynomial is the **maximum** among the sizes of the Jordan blocks associated with $\lambda$.